# gcc 7.1 parameters not reconized after compile

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I built GCC 7.1 successfully and installed it, however when I tried to compile with options like `-quiet`, `-imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu` and/or `-auxbase dummy` it does not recognize them. do I have to add these on compile somehow? These options are recognized by the compiler when installed though packages.

Comment: Why do you want to use these options? What do they do? Are they mentioned in the gcc documentation? I know they are mentioned in gcc -v --help but I have no idea what they are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These flags are recognized by the internal compiler executable, `cc1`, but not by `gcc`, which is the compiler driver (the driver is the high level compiler executable which orchestrates the build process, and is responsible for running `as` and `ld`, among other things).

For example, `gcc foo.c -o foo.o -v` results with this `cc1` command line on  Ubuntu 16.04:

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu foo.c -quiet -dumpbase foo.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase foo -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccds3WIY.s`

Note `-quiet`, `-imultiarch` and `auxbase` in the above.